# Change count down to count up

Tags: javascript, counter, countdown

This script counts down from 60 to 0 and stops when it reaches 0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
var counttx= "60";
var counterrx=setInterval(timerrx, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timerrx()
{
 counttx=counttx-1;
if (counttx < 0)
{
 clearInterval(counterrx);
 return;
}

document.getElementById("timerrx").innerHTML=counttx; // watch for spelling
}
</script>
```

Instead of counting down, I want the script to count up. I changed the `-` to a `+` in `counttx=counttx-1;` but then the following happend:

```
60
601
6011
60111
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like counttx is a string, and javascript is appending '1'.  Try:

```
counttx = +counttx + 1;
```

Edit: or just remove the quotes in the var statement:

```
var counttx = 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

If one operand of `-` operator is string and another is number JS converts the string to number. Thats why count down is working even if `counttx` is string. But when one operand of `+` is string and another is number JS converts the number to string and does a string concatenation. Thus you are getting 601, 6011 etc. instead of count up. To fix this you can declare `counttx` as integer.

```
var counttx = 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from `var countxx="60"`;

Write it as

```
var countxx=60;
```

and then change it to

```
counttx=counttx+1;
```

When you mention the value within quotes, it considers it as string and just appends 1 to the value, that is the reason your getting 601, 6011 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count from 0 to 60? If so swap the 60 and the 0 in your script and change this line `counttx = counttx + 1;` to `counttx = counttx - 1`. Also get rid of the `double quotes` around 60.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse var to integer first then increment it. Use counttx = parseInt(counttx) + 1;